# Understanding when events happen in Firestore for billing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to better understand which events in the Firestore API trigger the billing. For example, is the code below billed as one read and one write or just one write?

```js
db.collection("cities").doc("DC").update({ capital: true });
```

When getting back a list of documents, when does the read actually get billed? For example:

```js
const snapshot = await db.collection("cities").get();
snapshot.forEach((docRef) => console.log('First: ', docRef.data());
// ...execute some more code...
snapshot.forEach((docRef) => console.log('Second: ', docRef.data());
```

In this example I'm looping through the returned snapshot of data twice. Does the billing happen on the `.get()` or does it happen on each `docRef.data()`? Specifically, in these list cases I'm trying to figure out if I can hang on to the `snapshot` or if I should convert them to plain JSON objects. I know the docs and videos say not to optimize around billing, but at the same time I'd like to be smart about it so I don't have to refactor later.

Comment: 1 read = 1 document retrieved. So if you retrieve 2 docs you are billed 2 reads

Comment: Your example makes little sense as get() returns a promise https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: I updated the sample to include an `await` on the `get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first snippet you will be charged for a single document write operation.

For read operations you are charged when the server needs to read a document on your behalf, which in your second snippet happens when you call `get()`. So you'll be charged once for each document in `snapshot`, no matter how often you access the data in that snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

You will be billed only once as you get the documents only once. So in your case it will cost you 1 read per document in the collection `cities`

Comment: I understand that, but is the read billed when the snapshot is resolved or when data() is executed?